# CSS with IPhone Chat layout

Tags: html, ios, css, layout, chat

I'm trying to create a page wich will be used to send/receive SMS, I want to show when each SMS was sent/received but I can't seem to be able to align the date right...

Here is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xazvruqj/2/

EDIT: My jsfiddle was missing the actual CSS ...

This part in my CSS is causing me trouble :

```
.dateR{
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
    top: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 75%;
    font-style: italic;
}
.dateL{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    left: 2px;
    top: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 75%;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

As you can see the dates on the right are completly wrong, I would like them to be text-aligned to the right and under the message.

I thougth that using position:absolute for the date would make it easier but it was only true for the left side.

Thanks for reading this.

Comment: It'd be helpful if your jsfiddle included the full CSS so the problem could be reproduced in full there. If you run it with just the CSS you pasted in the question the dates aren't even visible anywhere.

Comment: Sorry I failed my jsfiddle, I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably other solutions out there - but it's easy enough if you just place the dates in their own containers and align them separately.

Here's a solution using a new CSS class "bubble-line":

```css
/* Bit of normalisation */

body {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #222;
  font: 0.8125em/1.5'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 400px;
}
img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.container {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
}
/* .bubble */

.bubble-line {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.bubble-line-right {
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
}
.bubble {
  background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(210, 244, 254) 25%, rgb(149, 194, 253) 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(210, 244, 254) 25%, rgb(149, 194, 253) 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(210, 244, 254) 25%, rgb(149, 194, 253) 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(210, 244, 254) 25%, rgb(149, 194, 253) 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(210, 244, 254) 25%, rgb(149, 194, 253) 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.25, rgb(210, 244, 254)), color-stop(1, rgb(149, 194, 253)));
  border: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  /* vendor rules */
  border-radius: 20px;
  /* vendor rules */
  box-shadow: inset 0 5px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  /* vendor rules */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 8px 30px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.bubble:before,
.bubble:after {
  border-radius: 20px / 10px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
.bubble:before {
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  bottom: 0;
  left: -7px;
  z-index: -2;
}
.bubble:after {
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #d2f4fe;
  bottom: 1px;
  left: -5px;
}
.bubble--alt {
  background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(172, 228, 75) 25%, rgb(122, 205, 71) 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(172, 228, 75) 25%, rgb(122, 205, 71) 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(172, 228, 75) 25%, rgb(122, 205, 71) 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(172, 228, 75) 25%, rgb(122, 205, 71) 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(172, 228, 75) 25%, rgb(122, 205, 71) 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.25, rgb(172, 228, 75)), color-stop(1, rgb(122, 205, 71)));
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}
.bubble--alt:before {
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 20px / 10px;
  left: auto;
  right: -7px;
}
.bubble--alt:after {
  border-bottom-color: #ace44b;
  border-radius: 20px / 10px;
  left: auto;
  right: -5px;
}
.dateR {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 75%;
  font-style: italic;
}
.dateL {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 75%;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="bubble-line">
      <div class="bubble ">Test</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bubble-line">
      <div class="dateL">11 mai 2015 12:02:02</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bubble-line">
      <div class="bubble bubble--alt">Test</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bubble-line-right">
      <div class="dateR">12 mai 2015 12:02:02</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bubble-line">
      <div class="bubble bubble--alt">TestTestTestTestTest TestTest Test Test TestTestTestTestTestTestTest</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bubble-line-right">
      <div class="dateR">12 mai 2015 12:02:02</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bubble-line">
      <div class="bubble ">TestTestTestTestTest TestTest Test Test TestTestTestTestTestTestTest</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bubble-line">
      <div class="dateL">12 mai 2015 12:02:02</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="bubble-line">
      <div class="bubble ">Test</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bubble-line">
      <div class="dateL">11 mai 2015 12:02:02</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bubble-line">
      <div class="bubble bubble--alt">Test</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bubble-line-right">
      <div class="dateR">12 mai 2015 12:02:02</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bubble-line">
      <div class="bubble bubble--alt">TestTestTestTestTest TestTest Test Test TestTestTestTestTestTestTest</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bubble-line-right">
      <div class="dateR">12 mai 2015 12:02:02</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bubble-line">
      <div class="bubble ">TestTestTestTestTest TestTest Test Test TestTestTestTestTestTestTest</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bubble-line">
      <div class="dateL">12 mai 2015 12:02:02</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

That way, you don't run into issues with floats stacking up on the same line, and don't break the  background image positions on the text bubbles.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing!

Answer (score 0):

Hi not sure if this will help.

Use on your .dateR

position:absolute;
left: 0; (Or wherever you want it)

No need for float:left with absolute positioning

Also, make sure the parent element is set to position:relative;

Comment: left:0 won't do it because the parent has his origin point on the bottom left of its div :/

Comment: Its a hack but this should get the dates aligned.

.dateR{
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    **left: -290px;**
    top: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 75%;
    font-style: italic;
}